# gulp-sass multiple css versions

Tags: sass, gulp

Based on the gulb file of foundation 6.4 I compile my sass files.
The goal is to compile the app.css and a backend.css and a rte.css

```
var gulp          = require('gulp');
var $             = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var autoprefixer  = require('autoprefixer');

var sassPaths = [
  'node_modules/foundation-sites/scss',
  'node_modules/motion-ui/src'
];

function sass() {
  return gulp.src('scss/app.scss')
    .pipe($.sass({
      includePaths: sassPaths
    }).pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
};

function rte() {
  return gulp.src('scss/Rte.Default.scss')
    .pipe($.sass({
      includePaths: sassPaths
    }).pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
};

function backend() {
  console.log('Backend\n');
  return gulp.src('scss/Custom.Backend.scss')
    .pipe($.sass({
      includePaths: sassPaths
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
};

function serve() {
  gulp.watch("scss/**/*.scss", sass);
};

// define the tasks
gulp.task('sass', sass);
gulp.task('rte', rte);
gulp.task('backend', backend);
gulp.task('serve', serve);

gulp.task('default', gulp.series([sass, rte, backend, serve]));
```

unfortunately I can compile app, rte, backend each on its own (commenting out the other tasks), but I can't compile all of them an once.

I only get "app.css", but not the other files.
I am a little bit lost in the gulp/references, tryed certain "similar" scripts/hints/tips - but I atways fail.

Do you know? I am sure you do!
Thank you for any help!

Comment: Have you tried importing the other two scss files into your app.scss file? Then gulp knows what to render.

Comment: I want them separated. 3 Files for different purpose. Not one monster CSS

Comment: You're meant to combine them, why keep them separate? But in that case you'd need to have Gulp render each scss file separately to a unique css file.

Comment: What if you lose the array notation: use `gulp.series(sass, rte, backend, serve)` instead in your `default` task?

Comment: You get no error message?  Does it say it is starting and finishing the tasks `rte` and `backend` and `sass`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an issue with this code:

```
function sass() {
  return gulp.src('scss/app.scss')
    .pipe($.sass({
      includePaths: sassPaths
    }).pipe(gulp.dest('css'));    // problem here
};
```

It is a little obscured because of your style but you are missing a `)`

```
   })).pipe(gulp.dest('css'));    // correct
```

and same in other tasks.

Comment: thankyou for pointing out this issue: I did delete some lines not of interest.... The script runs so far, exept the problem of multiple files